# Cannot connect to Couchbase Server on Debian

Tags: debian, couchbase

When I first installed Couchbase on Debian I could open localhost:8091 but after a restart of my computer it isn't possible anymore. I made sure the server is running with `systemctl status couchbase-server`. I can also exclude that a firewall is the cause of this problem.

When I start couchbase-server and check the status I get:

```
couchbase-server.service - Couchbase Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/couchbase-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-05-25 11:29:48 CEST; 3s ago
       Docs: http://docs.couchbase.com
   Main PID: 16412 (bash)
      Tasks: 43 (limit: 38359)
     Memory: 20.5M
        CPU: 165ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/couchbase-server.service
             ├─16412 bash /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -- -noinput
             ├─16420 /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-9.3.3.9/bin/beam.smp -- -root /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /opt/couchbase -- -noshell -setcookie nocookie -sname init -run init stop
             ├─16427 /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-9.3.3.9/bin/epmd -daemon
             └─16440 erl_child_setup 70000
```

And after 2 minutes the status is the following:

```
couchbase-server.service - Couchbase Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/couchbase-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-25 11:31:58 CEST; 1s ago
       Docs: http://docs.couchbase.com
    Process: 16412 ExecStart=/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -- -noinput (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 16412 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 175ms

Mai 25 11:29:48 106431 systemd[1]: Started Couchbase Server.
Mai 25 11:31:58 106431 couchbase[16420]: Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error:
Mai 25 11:31:58 106431 systemd[1]: couchbase-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mai 25 11:31:58 106431 systemd[1]: couchbase-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Edit: This problem appeared with version 6.6.0. I also tried the beta version 7.0.0 and that one worked.

Comment: Anything standing out in the log files? Which version of Couchbase Server is it?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that looks useful. Although I started the server today in most log files there weren't even entries for today. But I added information about the status that might help to find the cause of the problem.